# Get specific td data, use data in a link, replace td data with the link JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table generated by open data tables it generates perfectly. I need to isolate the last four cells on each row, store those values in a variable, and then make a link using the text in each cell (`url + “/“ + text variable + “>” text variable + “</a>”`).  This link will be unique to each cell and needs to overwrite current cell text in all of last 4 cells of each row in the table.  It will eventually be called on an onload event but onclick event is fine for now (testing etc).  This needs to be a JavaScript function or jQuery.

I have searched for a long time trying every possible way to do this and can come close but I can’t seal the deal.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The url for the table I’m working with is: http://mak-a-key.com/wp-content/themes/theme49645/tables/table-links.html

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.  I’ll write it up and let you know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the table, you can use the callback function **createdCell** and modify the cell's DOM.

*cellData*: gives you the actual data in the current cell

*rowData*: gives you the actual array of data in the current row

if you need the last 4 in one, just concatenate : 
rowData.nameCell2 + rowData.nameCell3.... and use it in the URL part.

Example:

```
$('yourTable').DataTable({
    columns: [
            {data: 'dataCell1'},
            {data: 'dataCell2',
                createdCell: function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                    // rowData contains all information for the actual row
                    // cellData contains information in your actual cell
                $(td).html("<a href="yourURL + cellData"></a>");
          }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Hi Thank you again for your help.  I've tried this solutions but it does nothing .  I've spent the entire day trying to find out how to do this and cannot find a solution.  This script will do what I want but it sets the link as the same for every cell I targetd with the class of selected:

Comment: Hi Thank you again for your help.  I've tried this solutions but it does nothing .  I've spent the entire day trying to find out how to do this and cannot find a solution.  This script will do what I want but it sets the link as the same for every cell I targeted with the class of selected:

Comment: function lastFour () {
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('td:nth-child(n+2)').addClass('selected');
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
            var y = $('.selected').html();
            var z = "<a href=" + "https://www.huyett.com/Products/Power-Transmission/Keystock/Oversize-Keystock/";
            var i;

            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].innerHTML = z + y + " target='_blank'" + ">" + y + "</a>";
              }

          });
        }

Comment: I may be using the script you gave me wrong.  I changed the 'yourTable' to my table id(table-container-table) and put static text(test) in for the $(td).html(); but nothing happens. and add the function name to the onclick event nothing happens though.  The console shows no errors.  Any help on this?  Thanks.

Comment: I finally figured out how to make it work.  Thanks for the help.